# How to identify which URL is attempting to access SMTP from browser

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, smtp, url

Opening a web page attempts to access SMTP server in the network. I am not able to identify exactly which URL is attempting for the same. Due to nature of the work, many tabs are open in the browser.

Even UFW is enabled to deny out for SMTP. Still machine is able to attempt SMTP request in the network.

UFW rules are as follow:

`25/tcp DENY OUT Anywhere`

`25/udp DENY OUT Anywhere`

Comment: UFW cannot prevent any programs from making an attempt to access SMTP server, but if properly configured, it should *make sure any such attempt will fail.*

Comment: "many tabs are open in the browser" - use browser developer tools on each tab to determine which one is the culprit

Comment: Thank you for your inputs